# How does ScalaTest analyzes assert expressions?

Tags: scala, scalatest

When ScalaTests are failing the test framework outputs a detailed error output like this:

```
assert(a == b || c >= d)
// Error message: 1 did not equal 2, and 3 was not greater than or equal to 4
```

How does it understand the structure of the assert expression? Does it use some Scala tricks to override comparison operators or does it have access to AST of Scala compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `assert` is provided by a macro, so - in short - yes, it has access to the AST.

If you are curious about the specific details, I suggest to take a look at the source code: https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/d40d278f2bb8e73431b942d87881fb6dbab75cb9/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/AssertionsMacro.scala

and

https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/4d785a085717444436fc5a1fa4736e9d2651a300/scalactic-macro/src/main/scala/org/scalactic/BooleanMacro.scala